# using if else in sql server subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure why the following subquery doesn't work in SQL Server, when I run the subquery by itself it works just fine, but as soon as I add

```
Select * from ([subquery]) as table1
```

the query doesn't run, SQL Server returns an error saying I have incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if', what syntax error exists here and how come it will work just fine otherwise?

Any pointers?

```
select * from (

    if datepart(MONTH, getdate()) >= MONTH('1/February/0000') 
    --after february we want the next years semesters, 

        begin
        select top 3 sem_name from semester_dates
         where datepart(year, start_date) < datepart(YEAR, getdate()) and sem_name not like 'summer%'
        end

    else 
        begin
        select top 3 sem_name from semester_dates  sd
        where datepart(year, start_date) >= datepart(YEAR, getdate()) and sem_name not like 'summer%' 
        end

    ) table1
```

Comment: You cannot have an `if` inside of a query like that, is this code in a stored procedure? Or where are you executing it from?

Comment: @bluefeet yes, this is inside a stored procedure... so what are my alternatives then?

Comment: What you have is not a subquery.  You could probably turn that into a table valued function though.

Comment: If it is in a proc and you just want the result set of the appropriate query to be returned, you need to have the outer "SELECT * FROM(...)".  Just let the query that executes return its rows to the caller.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables thanks- i didn't notice that, logic error on my part, i'll fix that in the question so it doesn't distract from the question.

Comment: @BStateham Thanks, if you put your comments as an answer i'll accept it. could you show an example of what you mean by 'let the query return rows to the caller'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to consider moving your if/else logic into a table valued function.  Something like this perhaps.  Note, I didn't check your logic, I just re-used this. You may need to adjust the code below accordingly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SemesterNames
(
  @ReferenceDate datetime
)
RETURNS @dates table 
(
  sem_name nvarchar(50) --check the data type
)
AS
BEGIN
  if datepart(MONTH, @ReferenceDate) >= MONTH('1/February/0000') 
    --after february we want the next years semesters, 
    INSERT INTO @dates (sem_name)
    select top 3 sem_name from semester_dates
     where datepart(year, start_date) > datepart(YEAR, @ReferenceDate) and sem_name not like 'summer%'
    end
else 
    INSERT INTO @dates (sem_name)
    select top 3 sem_name from semester_dates  sd
    where datepart(year, start_date) >= datepart(YEAR, @ReferenceDate) and sem_name not like 'summer%' 
END;
GO

SELECT * FROM SemesterNames(GETDATE());
```

Comment: Any reason to make it a table values function and not just a temporary table variable? DECLARE @SemesterNames TABLE (... ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using CASE, instead of IF.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT 
  (
    CASE 
        WHEN datepart(MONTH, getdate()) >= MONTH('1/February/0000')
            THEN
                (SELECT TOP 3 sem_name 
                 FROM semester_dates
                 WHERE datepart(year, start_date) > datepart(YEAR, getdate()) and sem_name not like 'summer%')
            ELSE
                (SELECT TOP sem_name 
                FROM semester_dates
                WHERE datepart(year, start_date) >= datepart(YEAR, getdate()) and sem_name not like 'summer%')
            END
  ) sem_name
) t
```

Comment: At its current form, this won't work. The `TOP 3` needs to be changed to `TOP 1`, otherwise the following error is thrown: 
`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the only effect of your conditional logic is that datepart(year, start_date) is strictly greater than, or greater than or equal to. So you could replace the whole thing with just a simple query like this:

```
    select top 3 sem_name from semester_dates
    where datepart(year, start_date) >= datepart(YEAR, getdate()) 
    and sem_name not like 'summer%'
    and (
         datepart(MONTH, getdate()) > MONTH('1/February/0000') or 
         datepart(year, start_date) = datepart(YEAR, getdate()
    )
```

In other words, the year of start_date is strictly > year(getdate()) unless, if the month is > Feb, then the year can equal it.

Answer (score 0):

If/else constructions are not supposed to work into a Select query.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular query, could you not acheive the desired result using a single SELECT with the February condition in your WHERE clause?

```
SELECT TOP 3
    Sem_Name
FROM
    semester_dates
WHERE
    sem_name not like 'summer%'
    and 
    (
        (datepart(month, getdate()) >= 2 AND datepart(year, start_date) < datepart(YEAR, getdate()))
        OR
        (datepart(month, getdate()) < 2 AND datepart(year, start_date) >= datepart(YEAR, getdate()))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(select datepart(MONTH, getdate()) >= MONTH('1/February/0000'))
    as department,
(select top 3 sem_name from semester_dates
    where datepart(year, start_date) < datepart(YEAR, getdate()) 
        and sem_name not like 'summer%') 
    as sem_name,
(select top 3 sem_name from semester_dates sd
    where datepart(year, start_date) >= datepart(YEAR, getdate())
        and sem_name not like 'summer%') 
    as top 3 sem_name 
) table
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN batch.PropertyId IS NULL THEN
(SELECT count(*) FROM vw_UtilMan_InspectionBatchAreaPropertyMeterStatistic WHERE BatchId = batch.Id)
ELSE
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfMeters
FROM UtilMan_Properties prop
INNER JOIN AssMan_Assets meter ON meter.UtilMan_PropertyId = prop.Id and meter.IsDeleted = 0
WHERE
prop.IsDeleted = 0
and prop.Id = batch.PropertyId)
END

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).